# Problem using void pointer as a function argument

Tags: c, function, pointers, argument-passing, void-pointers

I can't understand this result...

The code:

```
void foo(void * key, size_t key_sz) {
    HashItem *item = malloc(sizeof(HashItem));

    printf("[%d]\n", (int)key);

    ...

    item->key = malloc(key_sz);
    memcpy(item->key, key, key_sz);
}

void bar(int num) {
    foo(&num, sizeof(int));
}
```

And I do this call: `bar(900011009);`

But the `printf()` output is:

```
[-1074593956]
```

I really need `key` to be a void pointer, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
printf("[%d]\n", *(int*)key);
```

The key is a void pointer to the int, so you first need to cast to an int pointer, then dereference to get the original int.

Comment: Yeah, I tried `(int*)*key` but didn't work and `*(int*)key` never occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you cast the pointer to `int`, you are getting the *address* as the value. You need to dereference void pointers like any other. Only you cannot directly dereference `void *`, so you must first cast it to a pointer of the correct type, here `int *`. Then dereference that pointer, i.e. `*((int *)key)` (extra parentheses to clarify the precedence).

Comment: Yeah, I tried `(int*)*key` but didn't work and `*(int*)key` never occurred to me.